# implement mouse motion on pygame

Tags: python, pygame, 2d-games

I'm working on a clone of space shooter and I need to use the mouse to move the player, right now the player is moving to the left and right key on pressing the arrow keys.

## here's a fragment of my code.

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    ## scale the player img down
    self.image = pygame.transform.scale(player_img, (50, 38))
    self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.radius = 20
    self.rect.centerx = WIDTH / 2
    self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT - 10
    self.speedx = 0 
   

    ## unhide 
    if self.hidden and pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.hide_timer > 1000:
        self.hidden = False
        self.rect.centerx = WIDTH / 2
        self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT - 30

    self.speedx = 0     ## makes the player static in the screen by default. 
    # then we have to check whether there is an event hanlding being done for the arrow keys being 
    ## pressed 

    ## will give back a list of the keys which happen to be pressed down at that moment
    keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()     
    if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        self.speedx = -5
    elif keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        self.speedx = 5

    #Fire weapons by holding spacebar
    if keystate[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        self.shoot()

    ## check for the borders at the left and right
    if self.rect.right > WIDTH:
        self.rect.right = WIDTH
    if self.rect.left < 0:
        self.rect.left = 0
```

Comment: You want the player to follow the mouse at a fixed speed or just always be at the same X coordinate as the mouse?

Comment: yes want the player to follow the mouse at the X and Y coordinate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolve my problem using this.

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
        player.rect.topleft = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
self.rect.center (or assign as you wish) = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
```

This would give you (x,y) of the mouse and then set the player coords to this value

use this to make the mouse invisible in the pygame window or else you'll see the pointer as well as the player

```
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
```

Comment: Why isn't there an update() function in your player Class if you are using sprites? Plus are you checking user input in the class itself? How can I say to you where you need to put this code w/o looking at the entire code? All I can say set the position of the player to the current mouse position (preferably in update() func of player class as this is a sprite).

Answer (score 1):

use following code for mouse motion or click

```
if pygame.event.get() == MOUSEMOTION:
   x,y=mousex,mousey=event.pos
elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
   mousex,mousey=event.pos
   mouseClicked = True
```